# Difference between 事儿 vs 东西

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

What is the difference in meaning between 事儿 and 东西. As far as I understand both mean "thing".
All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

东西 often refers to some concrete object, while 事儿 means matter/affair/business.

你下午有啥事儿吗？- What are you up to this afternoon?

你在吃什么东西？- What are you eating?

Comment: 东西 (thing) could be abstract ideas too, e.g. 东西 in 有什么东西在阻碍我 could just be my own doubt

Answer (score 1):

You can specify them by differ these two phrases：
做事儿，买东西,
which partly mean：
do a thing， buy a thing.

Answer (score 1):

The former (事儿) is an intangible thing, (an event, a matter, something that happening...), and the latter (东西) is a tangible thing that you can purchase and use.

Answer (score 0):

Its somewhat of a matter of habitual usage and preferential thing way of referring both to, like you have said, 'things'.

I believe the former is more widely used with people from the Northern part of China particular around capital region, the latter is somewhat of a more general usage.

Comment: 事儿 corresponding to stuff too, not from Hong Kong (maybe not from Taipei)